# Testing a method with sub methods

Tags: apex, unit-test

I have a class where I call a function , which in turn calls various functions, ex:

```
Class foo{

void parentmethod(){
method1();
method2();
method3();
}

List<SelectOption> method1(){

// do something like: 
  List<SelectOption> options = new List<SelectOption>();

   Schema.DescribeFieldResult fieldResult =
  foo__c.field1__c.getDescribe();
   List<Schema.PicklistEntry> ple = fieldResult.getPicklistValues();

   for( Schema.PicklistEntry f : ple)
   {
      options.add(new SelectOption(f.getLabel(), f.getValue()));
   }       
   return options;

}

list<account> method2(){

// do something
}

list<account> method3(){

// do something
}

}
```

When I write a test method for the above code , I see if I call parentmethod() in my test method I can get 100% code coverage. But is it write way to get 100% coverage ? what about the individual methods1 ,2 and 3? Is the logic inside it considered as test cover( the logic is just like assignment , int i = val. there is not complex calculation in it.). Is it the write way to test?

```
@istest
static void testParentmethod(){
foo obj = new foo();
obj.parentmethod(); // gets a 100% coverage

}
```

Comment: A proper test would assert the values of method1, method 2 and method3

Comment: If there is no functionality in the methods 1,2,3. Is it needed to be covered then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically you should write your code so you would be able to test each method individually, but sometimes there's no need to test built in functions or functionality that is obvious, like assignment, so you can skip testing 1, 2, and 3 methods. The only things you should keep in mind are:

1. **What are unit tests for** - This one is very important. Unit test should not only show that there are bugs in your code (it never says, that there are no, as Dijkstra said), it should also prevent your logic from being destroyed in the future. So even if you think that there's no reason to test something, think of it as of the guard for the future. Perhaps even testing simple assignment might be a good idea.
2. **What are methods for** - if it contains only assignment, perhaps you should move the code inside the caller? In general, splitting code into many small methods is a good practice, but always use your common sense.

Comment: NIce answer! I have updated my question with a logic in method1 . I assume this logic does not need any unit testing, correct? pls let me know your views

Comment: This method has no side effects, it only returns some value, without even taking any parameters. It's also really simple, has no conditional statements and uses mostly built-in functionalities. Summing up, there's no need to test it separately, in my opinion.

Answer (score 1):

Test methods must be written to test the functionality and not to cover the code(Although sometimes it is required :) ).

You can just write a test method which check a particular logic,put some asserts to verify this.

I'm sure if you only test the functionality it will automatically cover other parts as well and you don't have to write test methods for them.

Comment: If there is no functionality in the methods 1,2,3. Is it needed to be covered then?

Comment: It is not required to write tests for all the classes and methods.Think from functionality perspective and that way these will be covered automatically.